# qrcode transparent background php

Tags: php, css, qr-code, transparent

Can anyone help me how to generate qr code with transparent background ( without white background ) and save as PNG?

Before this im using this library :

phpqrcode/qrlib.php

i try this and it save with white background

```
require_once BASEDIR."public/phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
$path = 'img/qrcode/';
$file = $path.'test.png';
$text = 'test';
QRcode::png($text,$file,'L','20');
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your code and tell us where you are stuck

Comment: i already edit..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpqrcode transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969645/phpqrcode-transparent-background)

Comment: that use library??